# Combining multiple RSS feeds

Tags: c#, rss

I've successfully used ["union" as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79197/combining-two-syndicationfeeds) to join two RSS feeds in a c# project, but we have a scenario where we could have up to a hundred RSS feeds to join together. What would be the best way with that number of feeds?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `SelectMany()` (shown here via LINQ) to flatten the feeds into a single sequence and then use `Distinct()` to filter out duplicates you've already seen:

```
var feeds = new[] {
    "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/silverlight",
    "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/wpf"
};

var items = from url in feeds
            from xr in XmlReader.Create(url).Use()
            let feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xr)
            from i in feed.Items
            select i;
var newFeed = new SyndicationFeed(items.Distinct());
```

`Use()` is an extension method [described here](http://solutionizing.net/2009/07/23/using-idisposables-with-linq/) to clean up the reader after it's used. You also might need to define your own `IEqualityComparer<SyndicationItem>` to use with `Distinct()`.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an XML Document with a single root node
- Read the Children of the root node of all secondary RSS feeds
- Append those children to the New XML Documents root node

To get around the "node already belongs to another document" issue, simply take the Inner XML from the root node, and append it to the Inner XML of the aggregated document.